# How to make content is vertical stacked with css

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-4

Maybe someone know this game

[image]

i want to make every each card in a column in stacked, here my fiddle [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Aditya_4420/wag65hp1/73/).

in my case i have a card wrapped in some `div` with maximum height, then if the card is out of range the card is not be collapse (hide) however it should be stacked top

this happen in my code
[image]

I want to make like this, every card is stacked
[image]

**HTML**

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="card card-1">
    <h4 class="header-title">
      Lorem Ipsum
    </h4>
    <div class="card-body">
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Doloremque iusto molestiae eos totam ea, ratione quis veritatis commodi,
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="card card-2">
    <h4 class="header-title">
      Lorem Ipsum
    </h4>
    <div class="card-body">
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Doloremque iusto molestiae eos totam ea, ratione quis veritatis commodi,
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="card card-3">
    <h4 class="header-title">
      Lorem Ipsum
    </h4>
    <div class="card-body">
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Doloremque iusto molestiae eos totam ea, ratione quis veritatis commodi,
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.wrapper{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  max-height: 75vh;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.card{
  padding: 0.4em 1rem;
  width: 250px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  margin: 0.5rem;
}
.card.card-1{
  background: salmon;
  border: 2px solid red;
}
.card.card-2{
  background: royalblue;
  border: 2px solid blue;
}
.card.card-3{
  background: greenyellow;
  border: 2px solid limegreen;
}
```

so, what should i do to make it happen?

Comment: I would have really liked to help but I am unable to because you didn't provide your code. Without seeing your code I or anyone else cannot help you. Edit your question and add a code snippet.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using the `z-index` property? it's used to specifies the stack order of an element.

for example :

```css
.wrapper{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  max-height: 75vh;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.card{
  padding: 0.4em 1rem;
  width: 250px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  margin: 0.5rem;
}
.card.card-1{
  background: salmon;
  border: 2px solid red;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0px;
  top: 0px;
  z-index: -3;
}
.card.card-2{
  background: royalblue;
  border: 2px solid blue;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0px;
  top: 15px;
  z-index: -2;
}
.card.card-3{
  background: greenyellow;
  border: 2px solid limegreen;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0px;
  top: 30px;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="card card-1">
    <h4 class="header-title">
      Lorem Ipsum
    </h4>
    <div class="card-body">
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Doloremque iusto molestiae eos totam ea, ratione quis veritatis commodi,
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="card card-2">
    <h4 class="header-title">
      Lorem Ipsum
    </h4>
    <div class="card-body">
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Doloremque iusto molestiae eos totam ea, ratione quis veritatis commodi,
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="card card-3">
    <h4 class="header-title">
      Lorem Ipsum
    </h4>
    <div class="card-body">
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Doloremque iusto molestiae eos totam ea, ratione quis veritatis commodi,
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: thank this actually work, but what if the data it displays is dynamic, in css you make range in each card example `top: 10px; top: 20px; top: 30;` in every card class. but we don't know how many the card is displayed

Comment: so is there any way to add distance it statically?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what you are trying to achieve with that as the text in the upper cards would become unreadable, but one way to do it would be the following:

```js
var topProperty = 0;
var increaseBy = 20;

$('.card').each(function(i, obj) {
    $(this).css('top', topProperty);
    topProperty = topProperty + increaseBy;
});
```

```css
#box{
  position: relative;
}

.card{
  position:absolute;
  width:200px;
  height:100px;
}

.orange{
  background-color: orange;
}

.purple{
  background-color: purple;
}

.yellow{
  background-color: yellow;
}

.green{
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="box">
    <div class="card orange">A</div>
    <div class="card purple">B</div>
    <div class="card yellow">C</div>
    <div class="card green">D</div>
</div>
```